# Azure function - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=7.0.0.0

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm trying to run a new function but it fails all the time in runtime.

I tried to update the dependencies but with no luck.

I also added <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>

csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>ref_name_v3</RootNamespace>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="LazyCache" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="LazyCache.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Expressions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ref1.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ref2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Took the Sample Code snippets from [Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-lazycache-in-your-net-core-application-beginners-guide-c41372b41591) & C# [Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-linq-expressions-in-c-sharp/) to check any breaking changes on Azure Functions .NET 7 Isolated with the given NuGet Packages `LazyCache`, `LazyCache.AspNetCore` and `System.Linq.Expressions` latest versions, didn't found any issues with them.

Below is the Code Snippets arranged with the .NET 7 Isolated Azure Function Project and the Application Code is in [my GitHub Repository](https://github.com/HariKrishna598/DotNet7IsolatedAzureFunctionsProject):

**.csproj file**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="LazyCache" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="LazyCache.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Expressions" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: sadly it didn't help, I used  .net 6 isolated and it worked. Thanks for the help